# List of topics for basic calculus (1st,2nd,3rd semester)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I am an computer science student, currently studying in 2nd semester. Therefore my math courses are pretty weak. Although I "aced" them, I still feel I could use some extra basic calculus knowledge in my life. What would be the "basic" topics that I could study to have a more solid calculus (maybe mathematics overall) knowledge? 
Here is a list of topics I had/plan to have:

- Matrices, determinants,rank,inverse matrix, linear equation systems (all with real numbers)
- Limits, function analysis (again real numbers in Cartesian coord. system)
- Derivatives- single and multivariable
- Analytic geometry (in Cartesian coordinates)
- Basic operations with complex numbers
- Integrals- indefinite, definite,double (in Cartesian and Polar coordinates)
- Differential equations (current topic)
- Laplace transform (it is still unclear whether this will be included in our course)
- Series

Comment: Take a peek at William Chen's [lecture notes](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/ln.html), they cover much of the undergraduate math curriculum quite well. In general, look for lecture notes and class websites, many have past homeworks and exams with solutions.

Comment: In addition to all this, a little Probability/Statistics would not hurt. A typical course would cover the first 6-7 chapters of Rohatgi-Saleh's *An introduction to Probability and Statistics*

Answer (score 2):

For limits, derivatives, and an introduction to complex numbers, all in the context of calculus, but done as an introduction to serious math, I recommend Spivak's  *Calculus*. He digs deeper into the proofs and concepts than most authors, but also gives plenty of practice in manipulation.